# jQuery objects and properties

Tags: jquery, object

```
var firstBodyChild = document.body.children[0];
$('li', firstBodyChild);

// make a selection within a previous selection
var paragraph = $('p');
$('a', paragraph);
```

This is an example from a guide on the site http://jqfundamentals.com.

A few things I don't understand:

1. the format `$()` creates an object as far as I understand. So that means `paragraph` is an object - but what are its properties? What kind of object is it?

2.

```
var firstBodyChild = document.body.children[0];
$( 'li', firstBodyChild );
```

I would love if someone could explain this part. `firstBodyChild` will be the `firstChild` in the body part, but what does the second line mean/do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `$()` is an alias for `jQuery()`, which might be more readable. So you are calling a function and pass parameters to it.
2. Usually, the first param is a selector, as you know them from CSS. The second param is optional and called the context.

Assuming you have two lists `ul` in your body and want to make the list elements of the first one coloured red, you could use the bodies `.children[0]` as context to only get this elements list items, as in your first code example.

You can then go ahead and use jQuery to get a list of all `li` elements, either in the whole document (by using `$('li')`), or within a specific context, for example, the first list `ul` you already saved in a variable, using `$('li', firstBodyChild)`.

The returned object of a call to jQuery is a wrapper for DOM nodes. So it stores the elements that can be identified by the passed query and a whole bunch of functions you can use to filter and modify those elements.

To finish this example, to dye those list elements red, you could use jQueries `.css` to modify the appearance of those elements.

```
var firstBodyChild = document.body.children[0];
$('li', firstBodyChild).css({color: 'red'});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The 'paragraph' variable becomes a jQuery object and can use the standard set of functions of jQuery.
2. The second line there indicates that jQuery should look for a <li> element in the context of 'firstBodyChild' element. See the documentation here for more details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 1):

`$()` extends an object - in this case a DOM element - with all standard jQuery methods.

And (IMHO):

`$( 'li', document.body.children[0])` is a confusing way of saying:

`$('body *:first li')`

In other words, second parameter passed to `$()` method defines the context where `li` elements should be found in.